# What does the "size" argument in fread() refer to?

Tags: c, fread

I'm trying to make a basic program which copies the header of a `.wav` file, this was my attempt:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main (void)
{
    FILE* input = fopen("input.wav", "r");
    FILE* output = fopen("output.wav", "w");
    
    uint8_t header [44];
    
    fread(header, sizeof(uint8_t), 44, input);
    fwrite(header, sizeof(uint8_t), 44, output);
    
    fclose(input);
    fclose(output);
}
```

However, after failing to make it work, I looked up how to do it and apparently

```
fread(header, sizeof(uint8_t), 44, input);
fwrite(header, sizeof(uint8_t), 44, output);
```

should be

```
fread(header, 44, 1, input);
fwrite(header, 44, 1, output);
```

This is very confusing to me, as I thought that the second argument was supposed to be the size of the type of data unit you want to `fread`. Can anyone help me understand what I'm missing? Many thanks.

Comment: opening a binary file in text mode in Windows is a common mistake

Comment: @M.M Aah yeah that's likely the actual problem. You should add that to your answer.

Comment: How do you know it failed? You don't check the return value of `fread` and `fwrite`.

Comment: It might be interesting to view the output file in a hex editor when you use 1, 44 with "r" + "w", then view it again when you do 44, 1 with "r" + "w" and then finally when you write the code correctly with 1, 44 "rb" + "wb".

Comment: @Lundin how does one view a file in a hex editor?

Comment: @BlueKhakis You download one and open the file? :)  [HxD](https://mh-nexus.de/en/hxd/) is decent, though these aren't really hard to implement yourself either. Basically it opens a file with "rb" and reads until EOF, then prints every byte as hex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first size parameter specifies the size of a single record. The second size parameter defines how many records you want to load. `fread` returns the number of records it loaded.

So if you have a structure which is 20 bytes, and you have a file where you have stored 5 of the records then you can pass it like this.

```
if(fread(ptr, 20, 5, strm) != 5)
    printf("Unable to load 5 records\n");
```

Alternativaly you could load the same file like this:

```
if(fread(ptr, 1, 5*20, strm) != 5*20)
    printf("Unable to load 5 records\n");
```

The effect is the same, but the first version is more readable, because usually you may read records not just "bytes". It's easier to understand in the context of your application logic. And of course you don't have to deal with calculating the number of bytes yourself, thus reducing a chance for errors.

The same applies to `fwrite`.

So in your above example I would rather write it like this:

```
  // Your header is 44 bytes long (which is sizeof) but you want to read ONE header
  if(fread(header, sizeof(header), 1, input) != 1)
     ... error reading 1 header ....
```

Answer (score 3):

`sizeof(uint8_t)` is guaranteed to be `1`  . Some people think it good style to use the `sizeof` expression instead of the number.

You can either write 44 "blocks" of size 1, or 1 block of size 44. In either case , you tried to write 44 bytes -- the writing part is the same either way.

The difference is in the return value, which reports how many blocks were successfully written.   So if you use the `1, 44` order then it will tell you exactly how many bytes were written. If you use the `44, 1` order then you will either get `0` or `1` as the return value (and no way to know if it partially succeeded).

The same consideration applies to `fread`.

---

The `FILE* input = fopen("input.wav", "r");` part is incorrect: this specifies to open the file in text mode, which may perform translations on the input, such as changing the line endings.

Instead, open in binary mode with `"rb"` mode string.

Comment: Ah, this seems to make more sense, thank you.

Comment: When you say "open in binary mode with `"rb"` mode string", does that mean "replace `r` with `rb`"? I'm not very experienced in programming, I'm sorry if it's a daft question.

Comment: @BlueKhakis You should replace both `"r"` and `"w"` with `"rb"` and `"wb"` respectively.